# jenkins use shared library in non default location

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Following 
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/
I use in my java project a shared library `vars/sendNotification.groovy` that is used in a jenkins pipeline in `src/main/resources/pipeline`.

I got this folder structure from
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Is it somehow possible to put the groovy script in `src/main/resources/` as well? On jenkins -> configuration -> Global Pipeline Libraries it doesn't give me options to specify a path of the shared library (the groovy script)

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer is no. Why do you want to?

Comment: was just wondering if I can have all main main resources in the same location. I can live with it though